# Can't maintain session value after header redirect

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
  <?php 

        $mysql_handle = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
            or die("Error connecting to database server");
        mysql_select_db($dbname, $mysql_handle)
            or die("Error selecting database: $dbname");
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>
        <h2>Sorry, it looks like you lost...</h2>
        <h3>Your score was: <?php echo $_SESSION["score"] ?>! If this was your highest score, it has been saved.</h3>
        <button id="restartButton" type="button" onclick="restart()" name="restart" class="btn btn-info">Restart</button>
        </center>
    </body> 
    </html>
    <script>
        //when restart is clicked 
        function restart()
        {
            header("http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~chathamb/CodingPractice/ImprovedPongGame/game.php");
        }

    </script>
    <?php 


        mysql_close($mysql_handle);
    ?>
```

This is my code in gameOver.php and I can't seem to figure out why my $_SESSION["score"] is not being maintained properly. My first time through testing, it displayed 4 correctly, now I'm having some issues even printing out the echo and it will not reset after the restart() function that executes the header redirect.

From my research, I think the issue revolves around the header() redirect, but I can't seem to figure it out. I tried an AJAX workaround but it didn't work.

And yes, session_start(); is at the very top of my code on my game.php code. The game.php code is pretty long and kind of messy so I will save you all from the pain of seeing that.

Comment: You're mixing PHP/JS. `window.location` is what you want in your javascript. `header()` is PHP.

Comment: `window.location.href` = `$url`, : )

Comment: header() is a php function, not a JavaScript function.  For redirecting with JavaScript, I would use window.location.href = "...".

Comment: Ahhh, wow, feeling pretty silly for that one. Thanks, guys. @Alan I don't have much of anything important on there but appreciate the suggestion. I took it down

Comment: So, I witch out the header() function to a window.location.href, it is redirecting correctly, however it still won't change my session variable of score's value. It is repeatedly telling me my score was 4. At the top of game.php I have session_start(); $_SESSION["score"]; and  $_SESSION["score"]++; in certain cases which are confirmed being triggered. Any ideas why the session variable isn't changing still?And apologize for not being very concise. It's my first post on here.

Comment: Not 100% about this, but I would try changing the URL in `restart()` to be a relative URL.  Perhaps, by providing an absolute URL, the browser thinks its a different website and not sending the appropriate session cookie.  If that doesn't solve it, I'd have to see where you're setting `$_SESSION["score"]`